# RxSwift, Sometimes .disposed get called without calling .subscribe

Tags: dispose, rx-swift

In rx code, .disposed get called without any doing job like flatmap, subscribe. This happens only when I build my app at first time.

Does anybody knows what happens here?

This is my code

```
HTTP.getSomething()
        .flatMap { (list) -> Single<Void> in

            return HTTP.getList(withList: list)
        }
        .subscribe(onSuccess: { (storeList) in
            log.debug("Finish!!!")
        }, onError: { [weak self] (error) in
            self?.presentAlert(error: error)
        })
        .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Comment: How do you know disposed gets called?

Comment: @tomahh You could know when the disposable.create { } block get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way the code you presented can possibly be disposed without attempting the work inside of the flatMap is if `getSomething` emits a completed without emitting a value, or if it emits an error, or if the disposeBag is deleted. One of those three things is happening.

Since you say it only happens on first build, I suspect that `getSomething` is trying to make a network call before it has all the info it needs which is causing it to emit an error.

Comment: You again! Thank you. The problem was that dispose bag was deleted. Thank you!